# Search vector vs. ALL others in Solr

Tags: machine-learning, solr, knn, cosine-similarity

Say I have a field in Solr which is an array of ints that looks something like this:

```
vector=array(469,323,324,119,74,58,68,59,49,40,32,26,21,17,14,12,10,9,7,5,-642,-184,-99,-84,-79,-63,-50,-38,-30,-21,-18,-16,-17,-16,14,25,52,21,15,93,53,52,32,15,61,29,346,20,69,72,38,165)
```

Is there a way to find either the `k-nearest neighbors` or the `cosineSimilarity` between this vector and that for all other documents matching a search in Solr?

I tried building a matrix manually but it was crashing Solr.

```
let(
a=search(satracks, 
    q="vector:*",
    fl="vector",
    qt="/export",
    sort="vector desc"
),

b=col(a, vector),
mat1=matrix(b),
mat2=transpose(mat1),
testvector=array(469,323,324,119,74,58,68,59,49,40,32,26,21,17,14,12,10,9,7,5,-642,-184,-99,-84,-79,-63,-50,-38,-30,-21,-18,-16,-17,-16,14,25,52,21,15,93,53,52,32,15,61,29,346,20,69,72,38,165),

k=knn(mat2, testvector,5)
)
```

The documentation only shows random samples.  I want to compare a vector to *every other vector* that matches a given search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using Solr 9. First you have to add to every document in solr vectorized field. Than you can use knn in query:

`&q={!knn f=vectorized_field topK=10}[your_vector]`